# C# can't properly decrypt message using my own RSA implementation

Tags: c#, encoding, arrays, rsa

I am trying to implement my own RSA implementation. Let's say public key is:

```
BigInteger e = 5;
BiInteger n = 14;
```

And private key is:

```
BigInteger d = 11;
```

I want to encrypt string `"B"` and decrypt it later. The problem is my decrypted message has no sense. Here are my functions.

```
public static void EncryptMessage(string message, BigInteger e, BigInteger n,BigInteger d)
{
    byte[] ascii = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
    var m = new BigInteger(ascii);

    var c= Encrypt(m, e, n);
    var cipherText = c.ToByteArray();
    DecryptMessage(cipherText,d,n);
}

private static BigInteger Encrypt(BigInteger m ,BigInteger e, BigInteger n)
{
   return BigInteger.ModPow(m, e, n);
}

public static void DecryptMessage(byte[] c,BigInteger d,BigInteger n)
{
    var cipherText = new BigInteger(c);  
    Decrypt(cipherText,d,n);
}

private static void Decrypt(BigInteger c, BigInteger d, BigInteger n)
{
    var decryptedNumber = BigInteger.ModPow(c, d, n);
    var decryptedMessage = decryptedNumber.ToByteArray();
    string S = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decryptedMessage);
    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted message: "+ S);
}
```

After decryped message I have cursor in a second new line and there is nothing printed there. No character, nothing at all. I think it has something to do with converting from `bytes` to `BigInteger` and viceversa but I can't make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `n` of 14 is too small to represent any useful value. A "B" in ASCII has a byte value of 66. So when you decrypt it, you should get back 10 (66 mod 14) or 0x0A. Use bigger primes to encrypt larger messages.

Remember that this "textbook" RSA is not secure. You would also need to implement a padding scheme such as OAEP or PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Comment: No problem. Did it work correctly with larger primes? (If it didn't you should not accept a solution before checking)

Comment: it worked! Now i am trying to divide given message so i can encrypt it with smaller n.

Comment: Note that RSA is quite slow and a message is usually not directly encrypted with RSA. Instead it is encrypted with a symmetric cipher liks AES with a random key. The AES key is then encrypted with RSA. This is called [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem).

Comment: Thank you for additional information. I will read and try to make my program better.